# Select multiple options from hashtable key value in JAVA/JSP

Tags: java, jsp, hashtable

NOTE: I am following old jsp's scriptlet practice. Please don't push me to use JSTL this time.

HI All,
I have method which returns Map type data
`hashtable.keySet()` return `[8, 5, 2]`
`hashtable.entrySet()` returns `[8=ad, 5=asxd, 2=asdas]`

And then I have Select Multiple in jsp.
I want to generate Select options using this MAP key value.
like this

```
<select id="XX" name="XX" class="left" multiple="multiple">
  <option id="opt1" value="8">ad</option>
  <option id="opt2" value="5">asxd</option>
  <option id="opt3" value="2">asdas</option>
</select>
```

EDIT: Here is my Map type method

```
public Map<Integer, String> getRuleTag(String bucketTagGroup) {
          logger.debug("Start Of getRule Rule");


            Map<Integer, String> x = new Hashtable<Integer, String>();
            try
            {
                //System.out.println(rs.getString("inbuckets"));
                String[]  a = bucketTagGroup.split(", ");
                for(int i = 0;i<a.length;i++){
                //System.out.println(a[i]);
                    int tagid = Integer.parseInt(a[i]);
                    String sql1 = "select bucketchargetag from IDC.BCTCHRTAG where  tagid = ?";
                    java.sql.PreparedStatement p =  conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
                    p.setInt(1, tagid);
                    ResultSet rs1 = p.executeQuery();
                    while(rs1.next()){
                        //System.out.println(rs1.getString("bucketchargetag"));
                        x.put(tagid, rs1.getString("bucketchargetag"));
                        //System.out.println(x.entrySet());
                    }

                }
            logger.info(x.keySet().toString());
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.debug(e.getMessage());
            }
            return x;
        }
```

PS: Values may increase or decrease time to time in multiple select.
This multiple select will be generated at runtime.
Please ask me if need more information on this.
Thanks.

Comment: is the map is available in jsp?means where you declared the map it is in jsp page?

Comment: @pikrut yes its available in jsp.

Comment: Please show how you declared hashtable..

Comment: `bucketTagGroup` will be comma separated String Like "6, 4, 7"

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="XX" name="XX" class="left" multiple="multiple">
<%for(Integer key_value : (Integer)hashtable.keySet()){%>
  <option id="<%=key_value%>" value="<%=key_value%>"><%=hashtable.get(key_value)%></option>
<%}%>
</select>
```

Try this. And try to avoid doing sriptlets inside jsp. This is not good practice.

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Integer in `Integer key_value : hashtable.keySet()`